# Can i somehow insert number multiple times into input?

Tags: javascript, html

this code while i click two times: 2
what i need: 11

```html
<div id='one'></div>
<input type="number" id='pin'/>

<script>
document.getElementById('one').onclick = document.getElementById('pin').setUp(1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id='one'></div>
<input type="number" id='pin'/>
<script>
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var pin = document.getElementById('pin');

one.onclick = function(){
    pin.value = pin.value + '1';
}
</script>
```